# Using Native JavaScript to Desaturate a Colour

Tags: javascript, colors

I have a colour picker where the user can specify a hex colour.

I also want a saturation slider where the user can adjust the saturation, and get the new hex colour as an output.

Is there a way I can, in JavaScript, convert a saturation value, and a hex colour, into a new hex colour?

So, say for example I have a value #FF0000 and a saturation of 50 (out of 100) how would I ascertain the new hex colour from this?

I can't use any libraries for it because I'm creating it as a plugin for my website, and I'm trying to keep it as light as possible.

Comment: `FF == 255` What's 50% of 255?

Comment: Check this website, it has a javascript colour picker with a saturation slider, and also has a link to the source code: http://hslpicker.com/#9C639B

Comment: That's great, but it makes heavy use of libraries. I'm trying to keep it as light as possible.

Comment: I've user a JS library called pixastic for dynamic desaturation of images using canvas before, maybe look into how the library does the calculations: http://www.pixastic.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5sfDQ/

```
$("#color, #saturation").change(function(){
    updateColor();
});

function updateColor(){
    var col = hexToRgb($("#color").val());
    var sat = Number($('#saturation').val())/100;
    var gray = col.r * 0.3086 + col.g * 0.6094 + col.b * 0.0820;

    col.r = Math.round(col.r * sat + gray * (1-sat));
    col.g = Math.round(col.g * sat + gray * (1-sat));
    col.b = Math.round(col.b * sat + gray * (1-sat));

    var out = rgbToHex(col.r,col.g,col.b);

    $('#output').val(out);

    $('body').css("background",out);
}

function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
```

Comment: If you view this demo in Chrome, you even get a color picker and a slider out of it.

Comment: I converted this not to use jQuery, so this works for me now: http://jsfiddle.net/danhanly/5sfDQ/4/

Comment: Could you explain the use of the constants 0.3, 0.6, 0.08? How does this always produce a gray?

Comment: @Hugheth they may not produce a perfect gray for everyone. They are based on average human vision. More info here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems

Answer (score 2):

```
function applySat(sat, hex) {
    var hash = hex.substring(0, 1) === "#";

    hex = (hash ? hex.substring(1) : hex).split("");

    var long = hex.length > 3,
        rgb = [],
        i = 0,
        len = 3;

    rgb.push( hex.shift() + (long ? hex.shift() : "") );
    rgb.push( hex.shift() + (long ? hex.shift() : "") );
    rgb.push( hex.shift() + (long ? hex.shift() : "") );

    for( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        if ( !long ) {
            rgb[i] += rgb[i];
        }

        rgb[i] = Math.round( parseInt(rgb[i], 16)/100*sat).toString(16);

      rgb[i] += rgb[i].length === 1 ? rgb[i] : "";
    }

    return (hash ? "#" : "") + rgb.join("");
}
```

---

```
console.log(applySat(50, "#ff0000")); // "#7f0000";
console.log(applySat(50, "ff0000")); // "7f0000";
console.log(applySat(50, "#fed")); // "#7f776f"
console.log(applySat(50, "fed")); // "7f776f"
console.log(applySat(20, "#addfaa")); // "#232d22"
```

Comment: This isn't desaturating, it's darkening.

Comment: @Shmiddty hmm.. thought that was it ? . So it's the other way around?

Comment: You're bringing the colors to black. You should be bringing them to gray. There are a couple of different ways to do this. You can use 128 as your gray, or you can calculate a gray based on the original color (more useful when desaturating images).

Comment: Your solution is simple, but unfortunately it doesn't achieve what I'm looking for. This isn't saturation, it's just turning it to black. It needs to go to grey.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use a library, see **[mjijackson's RGB to HSL conversion page](http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript)**.

Copy the code to do RGB hex to HSL (or HSV) conversions.  As the slider is moved, you'll need to use these to convert between the color models to get the saturation value, modify it, and then get the resulting rgb color back.

Note: [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) are standard color models.  A few of the other answers are proposing definitions of "saturation" that do not correspond to these standard color models.  Users will be confused as the alternate definitions will not give results consistent with what they'd expect from GIMP, Photoshop or other common graphics applications.

Answer (score 1):

Real simple and easy function, input your color, and add how much you want to desaturate it by.
it does a pretty good job, but its not perfectly accurate.

```
    function addSaturation(color, amount){
        var color = color.replace('#', '').split('');
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        for(var i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
            var newSaturation = 0;
            if(letters.indexOf(color[i]) + amount > 15) newSaturation = 15;
            else if(letters.indexOf(color[i]) + amount < 0) newSaturation = 0;
            else newSaturation = letters.indexOf(color[i]) + amount;
            color[i] = letters[newSaturation];
        }
        return "#" + color.join('');
    }
```

you can use positive or negative amounts as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the Javascript provided in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624139/1812984) to match your needs

To change the saturation of an element, shift each of the three HEX values simultaneously, bringing the values closer to 128 (half of 256).

```
background-color: #FF0000; // rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

to this...

```
background-color: #BF4040; // rgb(191, 64, 64)
```